# try to grab data between class tag with PHP DOMXPATH

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

I am trying to grab the data between two css class tag in my html doc.

Here the example.

```
<p class="heading10">text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p class="heading11">text text</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

I don't know how to grab the

data between that

class heading10 and heading11.

I tried `//p[@class="heading10"]//following-sibling::p]`, it will grab all `<p>` after the class heading10.

Comment: I doubt this is possible with an xpath query... but don't quote me there. However, you could grab the node above this and loop through it's children- storing each element to an array after the first instance of the class heading10, and stopping when you find the class heading11. Then, you can use your new array to parse the HTML however you need.

Comment: Mikel, any simple code. i am little lost.thx

Comment: this is what get so far. $pTag1 = $tPageXpath->query('//*[@class="Heading10"]/following-sibling::p'); i got total of 5 element. now sure how to the stop that loop when the element hit the heading11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
//p[@class="heading10"]/following-sibling::p[position()<count(//p[@class="heading11"]/preceding-sibling::p)]
```

**EDIT:**

A bit more explanations for @jpaugh:

The OP's xpath grabs all sibling `p` elements after the one with `class="heading10"`. I have added the restriction for `position()` of the these elements to be less than position of the `p` element with `class="heading11"`.

Following code is confirmed to be working with php 5.5, and does not work with php 5.4(thanks @slphp):

```
$t = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><p class="heading10">text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p class="heading11">text text</p>
<p></p>
<p></p></root>';

$d = DOMDocument::LoadXML($t);
$x = new DOMXpath($d);
var_dump($x->query('//p[@class="heading10"]/following-sibling::p[position()<count(//p[@class="heading11"]/preceding-sibling::p)]'));


class DOMNodeList#6 (1) {
  public $length =>
  int(2)
}
```

Please note, that if `<p class="heading10">` is not the first `p` element, than you probably need to subtract them:

```
//p[@class="heading10"]/following-sibling::p[position()<(count(//p[@class="heading11"]/preceding-sibling::p) - count(//p[@class="heading10"]/preceding-sibling::p))]
```

Splitting by lines for the sake of readability:

```
//p[@class="heading10"]
 /following-sibling::p[
     position()<(
         count(//p[@class="heading11"]/preceding-sibling::p) -
         count(//p[@class="heading10"]/preceding-sibling::p)
     )
  ]
```

Comment: This comment could use more explanation (such as how it differs from the OP's xpath).

Comment: jpaugh,, what is OP's xpath? i tried the Alex's suggestion. When i run the script, it's grabbing the 5 <p> elements below the <p class="heading10">. Is this help?

Comment: @user2574693 "OP's xpath" is the one in the question: `//p[@class="heading10"]//following-sibling::p]`. Basically your one. Please note I have edited it in the question because of a typo.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the detail code simple. I am testing now on my PHP 5.4.16 and doesn't work.. I am going to try update my php and try it again. Keep you post.

Comment: Alex's sample code work perfectly. I just tested out and it's able to grab what i am looking for.

Comment: @slphp, glad to know it helped. You can accepted the answer to indicate it is correct.